# Rewarded Video Ads Is Not Loaded

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to show rewarded video ad in my android application using Admob. If I run app with google sample ad unit ID, it work perfectly but if I change it to my rewarded ad unit ID, Ad is not loaded.

Comment: You have to watch logcat to see what happen, if is error 3 it mean that is no ad available on inventory

Answer (score 0):

What if there is no real problem with your ads/code/ etc. 
Newly created ads need some time to get available.

More info here:

> https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2993019?hl=en